# How you will implement join query for JDO

Tags: jdo

You have a query say :-

```
select p from profiles p, group g where p.profileId = g.profileId
```

How will you implement it using JDO. It could be basic but I am new to JDO and was not able to goolge something meaningful.

Comment: and what does the JDO spec say ? it has plenty of examples, as does the DataNucleus website

Comment: didnt get you quitely

Comment: As the previous commenter said, the "JDO spec" is a public document so it is suggested that you read it since it tells you all about JDO and JDOQL. If using DataNucleus then it has documentation which also tell you how to form a JDOQL query. That should be a prerequisite before having a problem. When you've read those and told people what you've tried then ask your question based on that knowledge

Answer (score 0):

In JDOQL you dont really have something like a JOIN. As @sihaya mentioned, retrieving a object will also fetch all of its members (depending on the configured fetch type ("eager" will load everything and "lazy" will load it later))

Looking at the docs, you can use something similiar, called "unbound variables":

> Unbound variables, which serve as a replacement for the JOIN operation of SQL

> Unbound variables are supported by ObjectDB, but considered optional by JDO. Queries with unbound variables are similar to JOIN queries in SQL because every combination of variables has to be checked for every candidate object. Just like JOIN queries in SQL, queries with unbound variables may become very slow, so caution is needed when using them.

Here is the link: https://www.objectdb.com/database/jdo/manual/chapter7

Answer (score -1):

In JDO and other object-relational mapping frameworks such as JPA the join condition for a relation between two entities is inferred from the meta-model.

In your example you presumably have two entities Profile and Group and a n-1 relationship from Group to Profile. Then given the following entities:

```java
@PersistenceCapable
public class Group {
     private Profile profile;
     ...
}
```

and

```java
@PersistenceCapable
public class Profile {
     ...
}
```

Executing the following JDO query will select all profiles that are referenced by a group:

```
select g.profile from Group g
```

Comment: This is not a join.